# how to execute automatic test on Asterisk?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, asterisk, voip, asteriskami

I am a Software testing engineer.My job is to test the function of a VOIP server,based on asterisk.

Since my job is completely manual test,I just feel it boring,and would be replaced by a man who don't have a bachelor degree.

I want to know whether I can do automatical test on Asterisk.How to do it?

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have read this article on SO

[Unit/integration testing Asterisk configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173467/unit-integration-testing-asterisk-configuration)

You for sure can do automatic test for asterisk, using asterisk dialout/ AMI event monitor. But that is task-specific question.

You also can use nagios project to do some simple check(write script) for you

Comment: hi arheops can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391634/set-waiting-tone-for-asterisk-agi-function-processing it would be a great help.