# Send pulse before call answer

Tags: asterisk, dialplan

Problem:
I bought a local DID and when I call it the phone is mute until the connection is executed in Asterisk and then immediately begins the synthesized speech.

How it should be:
I would like to make the customer's phone (who is calling) hear the pulse sound a few times. When I call a normal number, even before the other phone rings, it starts to hear pulse sounds. PS: On my DID server you have no option to configure anything.

How I did it:
I bought a local phone number (DID) that automatically redirects to a SIP from the same service. So I set up my Asterisk server to connect to this SIP account, and the dialplan tried to put a wait value in the answer, but it did not work.

I tried to put a value for the "Answer(5)" command, but the result was: The call is answered, it is silent for 5 seconds and then it executes the next command. When I would like to sound the pulse before showing the answered call. (Before answering the call my dialplan takes 2 seconds to open the necessary settings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Send `Progress()` then `Ringing()` or `PlayTones(ring)`

I've seen a few providers where we've needed to indicate ringing by way of [early media](https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-cmd-progress), e.g.:

```
exten => 500,1,Progress()
exten => 500,n,Wait(1)
exten => 500,n,Dial(PJSIP/121)
exten => 500,n,Hangup()
```

*or*

```
exten => 500,1,Progress()
exten => 500,n,PlayTones(ring) <-- OR USE MAYBE Ringing() HERE INSTEAD?
exten => 500,n,Dial(PJSIP/121)
exten => 500,n,Hangup()
```

*etc…*

#### See also

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+16+Dialplan+Applications:

- [Progress()](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+16+Application_Progress)
- [Ringing()](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+16+Application_Ringing)
- [PlayTones(**ring**)](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+16+Application_PlayTones)
- [Dial()](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+16+Application_Dial) *especially flags `R` and `r(ring)`*

Comment: There's also `Proceeding()` hmm not sure of the semantics of it all though.

Answer (score 0):

You should create music on hold file with pulse+needed silence.

After that you have start moh using AGI action Set Music like described here

[Set waiting tone for asterisk agi function processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391634/set-waiting-tone-for-asterisk-agi-function-processing)